# Random different colored backgrounds on post grid layout

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, background, alternating

I am wanting to use this plugin to display blog posts, but instead of having the image as the background, the client wants different colored images. From another post on here I have figured out the code I believe to do this BUT I can't get it to take on the website!. Here is the code I made that seems to work here. 
[Example where code is working.](https://jsfiddle.net/tyrii/r1dzy0ww/1/#&togetherjs=uFSrGLrSb5)

And here is the website in question at the moment. 
[The div site where it isn't working like it should...](http://tdgclients.com/)

You will see that all of the colors are the same and not alternating like they should be...
Any helpful advice would be greatly appreciated on why this isn't working.

Here is the CSS and JS that is in the jsfiddle above.

The CSS:

```
.custom_tdgclients_grid{width:20%;height:90px;display:inline-block}
.custom_tdgclients_grid{background:#a7948b}
.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(2n){background-color:rgb(232, 73, 73)!important;}
.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(3n){background-color:rgb(83, 71, 65)!important;}
.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(4n){background-color:#e8d2af!important;}
.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(5n){background-color:rgb(131, 119, 113)!important;}
.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(6n){background-color:rgb(216, 184, 133)!important;}
.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(7n){background-color:rgb(201, 93, 93)!important;}
.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(8n){background-color:#e8d2af!important;}
```

And the Javascript:

```
$('.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(2n)').css({'background-color':'rgb(232, 73, 73)'});
$('.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(3n)').css({'background-color':'rgb(83, 71, 65)'});
$('.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(4n)').css({'background-color':'#e8d2af'});
$('.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(5n)').css({'background-color':'rgb(131, 119, 113)'});
$('.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(6n)').css({'background-color':'rgb(216, 184, 133)'});
$('.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(7n)').css({'background-color':'rgb(201, 93, 93)'});
$('.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(8n)').css({'background-color':'rgb(181, 128, 101)'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `n` from `2n`, `3n, etc…

If it doesn't work try to identify them with their parents like :
`#parent .custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(2)`

Hope, it'll work :)

Comment: Looking at the div website, what do you think the parent is? There's so much going on there with their lovely wordpress short codes I can't figure out which one is the parent. I tried removing the **n** and using the code as it is but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I simplified it to this but it seems to still not work. .vc_gitem-zone.custom_tdgclients_grid:nth-child(1){background-color:#a7948b;}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the code for fixing this. I am going to post it here for anyone that may need it. Identifying them with their parents I think was key!!

```
#x-content-band-4 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(1) .custom_tdgclients_grid {background-color: #a7948b;}
#x-content-band-4 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(2) .custom_tdgclients_grid { background-color: rgb(232, 73, 73);}
#x-content-band-4 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(3) .custom_tdgclients_grid { background-color: rgb(83, 71, 65);}
#x-content-band-4 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(4) .custom_tdgclients_grid {  background-color: #e8d2af;}
#x-content-band-5 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(1) .custom_tdgclients_grid { background-color: rgb(131, 119, 113);}
#x-content-band-5 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(2) .custom_tdgclients_grid {  background-color: rgb(216, 184, 133);}
#x-content-band-5 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(3) .custom_tdgclients_grid { background-color: rgb(201, 93, 93);}
#x-content-band-5 .vc_grid .vc_pageable-slide-wrapper .vc_grid-item:nth-child(4) .custom_tdgclients_grid { background-color: #e8d2af;}
```

Then just do the same for the JS side code.

Comment: This is what I said…